# Fetch primary key generated by sequence using jdbctemplate / jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, oracle11g

The situation is as follows:

I have one table(GUI_FILTER) and one sequence(GUI_FILTER_SEQ)
I am inserting data using springjdbctemplate, also can use core jdbc as well. 
In the insert query I am retrieving sequence.nextval and also using a keyholder to fetch that back to java as below. 
I have tried several ways like using

```
returnRowCount = namedJdbctmplt.update(sql.toString(), namedParameters, keyHolder, keyColumnNames);

returnRowCount = jdbctemplate.update(psc, keyHolder);
```

both are failing,

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression



StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append(" Insert Into MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER ");
        sql.append(" (FILTER_PRESET_ID,USER_ID,FILTER_PAGE_TXT,FILTER_DISPLY_NM,FILTER_DATA_TXT,ROW_CREATE_TMS,LAST_UPDT_TMS ) ");
        sql.append(" values(Select MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,null from dual) ");
        final String sqlQuery = sql.toString();
```

If I remove the sequence generation part Select `MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER_SEQ.NEXTVAL` to something constant like 30 or so it is working fine.

**Is  there any way to get sequence value as insert command and also at the same time fetch the primary key using jdbc ?**

Complete code is as below.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, rollbackFor = DataAccessException.class)
public Long addFilterPreset(final String userId, final String filterPageCd,
        final String filterPresetDisplayName,
        final String serializedTaskBrowserSearchObj) {

    logger.debug("Start of FilterPresetDaoImpl - addFilterPreset() method");

    if(!countSavedFilterPresets(userId,filterPageCd))
        return null;

    //StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    //sql.append(" Insert Into MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER ");
    //sql.append(" (FILTER_PRESET_ID,USER_ID,FILTER_PAGE_TXT,FILTER_DISPLY_NM,FILTER_DATA_TXT,ROW_CREATE_TMS,LAST_UPDT_TMS ) ");
    //sql.append( "Values( Select MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:userId,:filterPageCd,:filterPresetDisplayName,:filterPresetData,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,null)" );

    /*parameterMap.put("userId", userId);
    parameterMap.put("filterPageCd", filterPageCd);
    parameterMap.put("filterPresetDisplayName", filterPresetDisplayName);
    parameterMap.put("filterPresetData", serializedTaskBrowserSearchObj);
    */
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append(" Insert Into MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER ");
    sql.append(" (FILTER_PRESET_ID,USER_ID,FILTER_PAGE_TXT,FILTER_DISPLY_NM,FILTER_DATA_TXT,ROW_CREATE_TMS,LAST_UPDT_TMS ) ");
    sql.append(" values(Select MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,null from dual) ");
    final String sqlQuery = sql.toString();

    logger.info("SQL Add Filter Preset Query : {}", sqlQuery);
    int returnRowCount = 0;
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    final String[] keyColumnNames = {"FILTER_PRESET_ID"};
    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource(parameterMap);

    PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreator()   {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                throws SQLException     {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery, keyColumnNames);
            ps.setString(1, userId);
            ps.setString(2, filterPageCd);
            ps.setString(3, filterPresetDisplayName);
            ps.setString(4, serializedTaskBrowserSearchObj);
            return ps;
        }
    };

    try{
        long startValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //returnRowCount = namedJdbctmplt.update(sql.toString(), namedParameters, keyHolder, keyColumnNames);
        returnRowCount = jdbctemplate.update(psc, keyHolder);
        long endValue = System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("Filter Preset added in {} seconds", (endValue - startValue)/1000);
    }catch(Exception e){
        logger.info("Exception while adding filter preset - " + "userId : "+userId+" filterPageCd : "+filterPageCd +" filterPresetData : "+serializedTaskBrowserSearchObj);
    }finally{
        logger.debug("End of FilterPresetDaoImpl - addFilterPreset() method");
    }
    if (returnRowCount > 0)
        return keyHolder.getKey().longValue();
    return null;
}
```

Error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the VALUES keyword when inserting a result from query.

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append(" Insert Into MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER ");
        sql.append(" (FILTER_PRESET_ID,USER_ID,FILTER_PAGE_TXT,FILTER_DISPLY_NM,FILTER_DATA_TXT,ROW_CREATE_TMS,LAST_UPDT_TMS ) ");
        sql.append(" (Select MAPS_AMPS.AMPS_GUI_FILTER_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?,?,?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,null from dual) ");
        final String sqlQuery = sql.toString();
```

To get an inserted value try using RETURNING clause: some details are discussed in this post [Oracle's RETURNING INTO usage in Java (JDBC, Prepared Statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320205/oracles-returning-into-usage-in-java-jdbc-prepared-statement)

However, you can use RETURNING clause for INSERT only if you use the VALUES keyword, so you can't have both. As it's discussed here: [PLSQL Insert into with subquery and returning clause (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325033/plsql-insert-into-with-subquery-and-returning-clause-oracle)