# How to delete records and return them in one statement? SQL/Java

Tags: java, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm having the hardest time figuring this out. I know there must be a way to do it and I'm probably very close (or maybe not). I want to delete a set of records from a table and return the records that were deleted in one statement. The table is a queue, and I need to pop some records off of it.

This gets the job done with 2 statements:

```
select id, add_date from my_queue where rownum <= 10;
-- save for processing
delete from my_queue where rownum <= 10;
```

**How can I combine these into 1 statement and then read the results in Java?**

I've looked at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320205/oracles-returning-into-usage-in-java-jdbc-prepared-statement) and I've tried to implement both methods in the question, however, in my case I have 2 columns to output and I need to use the `bulk collect into` clause, so the output will be a table. Doing it this way, I can't figure out what I need to do to properly define and register the output to execute the anonymous PL/SQL statement.

Here is my closest attempt:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append("BEGIN ");
sql.append("  delete from my_queue where rownum <= 10 ");
sql.append("  returning _id into ?; ");
sql.append("END; ");

CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall(sql.toString());
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
//cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
//cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.ARRAY);

cstmt.execute(); // throws error, see comments below
```

Here are the various errors on execute based on the output TYPE registered:

> Using CURSOR: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CURSER got NUMBER`
>
> Using NUMBER: `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`
>
> Using ARRAY: `ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation`

Comment: why don't you just run the select statement before the delete statement in your begin/end block?

Comment: @Sebas - will that block other operations on that same table? i.e. What if the select runs, some other operation inserts, and then the delete runs... will the other operation wait for the PL/SQL block to complete before insertting?

Comment: Select statements do not lock.  See here for more on what DML operations do or do not include locking: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/ap_locks001.htm#SQLRF55502

Comment: OK, so the real problem is not "how can I do it all in one statement." Rather, it is "how can I delete ten rows and also show them in a SELECT query - and make sure it's the SAME rows even if there are other transactions on the table." You can't do it all in one statement; there is no combined SELECT/DELETE statement in SQL. It's also not obvious exactly what the requirement is; what if you identify ten rows, but by the time you get to delete, three rows were already deleted by another user? Is it OK to just delete the other seven?

Comment: Once you open the transaction nothing can change your view of what's in the tables. You're safe. It's the whole point of it. It also means that if your delete statement (or one done from another request) will block your transaction until it's finished. It's not necessarly an issue, just make sure the query is optimized.

Comment: I'm not certain how the jdbc provider will react to this though. They usually get setup for either select of update/insert/delete statements. I'm not certain. If you indeed have a problem, I'd suggest you create a stored procedure containing this code and you call it instead of creating a dynamic begin/end block on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined solutions from several different posts/websites and came up with a working solution using the `bulk collect into` clause:

```
create or replace type queue_record as object (
  id number(10),
  add_date date
);

create or replace type my_queue_type as table of queue_record;

create or replace procedure pull_from_queue (
  pull_size in number,
  pulled_records out sys_refcursor
)
is
  tbl my_queue_type;
begin

  delete from my_queue
  where id in (
    select id from ( select * from my_queue order by add_date )
    where rownum <= pull_size
  )
  returning queue_record(id, add_date)
  bulk collect into tbl;

  open pulled_records for
  select * from table(cast(tbl as my_queue_type)) order by add_date;

end pull_from_queue;
```

Comment: For those downvoters, please tell me how this solution is incorrect and doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

you can `plsql` associative arrays to store the selected data and the delete your records from table. here is the pl/SQL example.

```
/* Formatted on 12/20/2016 3:45:29 PM (QP5 v5.277) */
DECLARE
   TYPE type_rec IS RECORD
   (
      Employee_id     NUMBER,
      Employee_name   VARCHAR2 (30)
   );

   TYPE type_aa IS TABLE OF type_rec
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

   l_var1   type_aa;
BEGIN
   FOR loop_aa IN (SELECT ROWNUM rn, Employee_id, Employee_name
                     FROM employees                
                  )
   LOOP
      l_var1 (loop_aa.rn).Employee_id := loop_aa.Employee_id;
      l_var1 (loop_aa.rn).Employee_name := loop_aa.Employee_name;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
            'Employee ID: '
         || loop_aa.Employee_id
         || ', Employee Name: '
         || loop_aa.Employee_name);
   END LOOP loop_aa;

   -- Delete records here
  DELETE FROM employees;
  --Commit;

END;
/
```